# All options except 'Delete Volume' greyed out for primary partition in Windows 10 Disk Management

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, disk-management

I'm trying to extend my primary partition in Windows 10, using the OS's Disk Management tool. I want to extend it into the unallocated space to the immediate right in the image below. These options are not greyed out for other volumes (I have just shrunk, formatted, deleted and extended other partitions in the process of moving this unallocated space to the immediate right of the volume I want to extend into it.)

I have tried downloading the AOMEI partition assistant, and it does not even detect the primary partition.

Why are these options greyed out for the primary partition, and how can I fix it in order to extend the volume?

[image]

Comment: You can give a try to [EaseUs](https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-free.html). Take a look to this [guide](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/extend-system-partition-windows-10.html)

Comment: The unallocated space needs to be right next to C:, to the right side, otherwise windows will not offer it, easeus can do it but back up the entire hard drive before doing so, easeus can make a full disk image also.